# Reload field value modified in DB by trigger after Insert/Update

Tags: entity-framework, triggers, entity-framework-4.1

I have an entity with a string property mapped to a nvarchar field in the DB. I use an after insert/update trigger to set the value of this field. By default EF will not load the value of this field after insert/update - only identity fields are reloaded from DB after insert.

I've tried to change the **StoreGeneratedPattern** option on this field to **Computed** (which seems like the right way to do that) but I get the error:

> The store generated pattern 'Computed'
>   is not supported for properties that
>   are not of type 'timestamp'  or
>   'rowversion'.

Does it mean that EF supports reloading only timestamps? 
How can I force EF to load the values of columns of other types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a bug. I just reproduced this behavior and [posted a question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a6d182bd-5027-4793-bfd9-ef88a44ec6bc) to MSDN forum. This works without any problem when using EDMX and model first.

Comment: Hi Ladislav! Thanks for the answer - btw, I'm using EDMX with POCO T4. My current workaround is to call DbEntityEntry.Reload().